# sendmail default mail path

Tags: sendmail, dovecot

I have just configured the postfix+dovecot and its working fine as I tested with configured in Outlook. Same way I am trying to setup a sendmail+dovecot,
The mail problem I am facing here is the mail-directory path of sendmail.
In postfix and dovecot I have configured /home/user/Maildir ,but in sendmail I am unable to find the exact parameter where I set the directory path ?
Particularly in /etc/mail/sendmail.mc file ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, neither Postfix nor Sendmail are in charge of the location of users' mailboxes. Both of them hand off local mail delivery to a local delivery agent and it is the local delivery agent that is responsible for knowing the location and format of users' mailboxes.

In your case, since you are using Dovecot with Maildir folders located in each user's home directory, the best choice of local delivery agent to use is probably [Dovecot's own LDA](http://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA). Being a part of Dovecot, the Dovecot LDA uses Dovecot's own configuration to set the location and format of user's mailboxes, so you can't go wrong.

In Sendmail, the path to the local delivery agent is set with the `m4` macro `LOCAL_MAILER_PATH`. In Postfix, it is set with the configuration directive `mailbox_command`.

Comment: In postfix main.cf I have found  " # The home_mailbox parameter specifies the optional pathname of a
# mailbox file relative to a user's home directory. The default
# mailbox file is /var/spool/mail/user or /var/mail/user.  Specify
# "Maildir/" for qmail-style delivery (the / is required).
#
#home_mailbox = Mailbox
home_mailbox = Maildir/   "    I just want to know what the exact similar parameter in sendmail configuration file ???

Comment: Finally got your point !!!   just edited the configuration in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf   #   mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
   mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
#   mail_location = mbox:/var/mail/%d/%1n/%n:INDEX=/var/indexes/%d/%1n/%n
thats it